# Postman return null data even if data exist

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, query-builder

I have no idea why it's not working even though the data exist.

Query

```
$employee = Employee::where('email', request('email'))->first();

if(!$employee)
{ 
   return response()->json(['error' => 'User not found.'], 401);
}
```

Api.php

```
Route::post('employeelogin', 'EmployeeController@employeeLogin');
```

Error in Postman `"error": "User not found."`

Comment: how you get data in postman?

Comment: There is mistake in your `request('email')`

It should be `$request->email`

Comment: @KamleshPaul https://imgur.com/ghRBJpl

Comment: @Ruchi didn't work, still getting the same error `user not found`

Comment: try `dd($employee);` and check if your `$employee` get any data or `NULL`

Comment: $employee = Employee::where('email', request('email'));
$qry = str_replace(array('?'), array('\'%s\''), $employee->toSql());
$qry = vsprintf($qry, $employee->getBindings());
dd($qry);

Dump query in your database and check if you get data there or not

Comment: if conditon should check for if $employee varibale is null or not, so check it for `if(empty($employee))`

Comment: @Ruchi I am sorry but how do we use `dd($employee);` in the controller?  I am new and I have never used this before.

Comment: `$employee = Employee::where('email', $request->email))->first();
dd($employee);`

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/echoing-dd-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r/

Comment: @KamleshPaul this is what i get after using `dd(Employee::all());` Screenshot: https://imgur.com/yj7muUo

Comment: @Ruchi with `dd($employee);` it was giving me a very complicated error in the script, here is the screenshot: https://imgur.com/zwV7YxF but when I tried `dd(Employee::all());` it shows me data in the script, screenshot: https://imgur.com/yj7muUo

Comment: You can click on preview button and it will not be complicated anymore. And on `line 23` it says `NULL` that you don't have any Employee with the given email ID

Comment: @Ruchi that's the thing, i do have that entry in my database.. here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/py5F91N

Comment: send a result of `dd($request->all())` ;

Comment: @Ruchi it's showing data with `dd(Employee::all());` screenshot: https://imgur.com/PtqDtQt

Comment: @KamleshPaul here's the screenshot of preview https://imgur.com/PtqDtQt

Comment: then now check `dd(request()->all())`

Comment: @KamleshPaul this is what i am getting now, screenshot: https://imgur.com/GVNEE3f

Comment: Can you show the whole method?

Comment: @HassanSaeed this is issue

Comment: @KamleshPaul i don't understand, what is the issue?

Comment: @jeremykenedy here https://imgur.com/caedpqZ

Comment: in postman send from `x-www-urlencoded` tab i guess

Comment: Your request is not proper
it should show
`[
   'email' => 'example@gmail.com'
]`

Comment: show a postman tab from where you passing email.

Comment: @KamleshPaul it worked if i am sending data in `JSON` format in Postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked if i'm sending data in `JSON` format in Postman

Answer (score 0):

When using postman to test api
first of all in header section add this

> X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest

then using the x-form-data section, not the form-data section